# How to use NaCl with Java under Windows

Tags: java, encryption, implementation, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I recently found the library [Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) and was glad that there are also [Bindings for Java](http://doc.libsodium.org/bindings_for_other_languages/README.html). Unfortunately, the libraries don't appear to work with Windows because they were developed for other systems.

How can I use the libraries under Windows (if possible)?
Are there any alternative libraries for Java?

Comment: They claim in their readme that it works with Windows.

Comment: Agreed -- the [kalium installation instructions](https://github.com/abstractj/kalium#installation) are kind of terse, but they never say it *doesn't* work on Windows. If you've tried to install there libraries, but couldn't get them to work, it would help if you described the specific issue you got stuck on. (Also, this question might be better suited for [so] in any case, since it's only tangentially related to cryptography.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that page for other bindings, you find the Java binding is called Kalium. You'll see it requires Apache [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). So I went and got that (at the bottom it explains how to install maven, but basically you just add some environment variables).

Now on to kalium, I got it from [their abstract on github](http://abstractj.github.io/kalium/). I needed `mvn clean install` from the directory in order to install it in Maven. After changing directory to the unzipped Kalium folder I ran the specified command (which is telling Maven to get the files and install Kalium). This will handle the rest of the set-up.

Then it's just a matter of adding it as a dependency in your Maven projects as per the Kalium readme. As for libsodium: it is a library that works with MinGW, and VisualStudio in Windows. So if you want to do C/C++ coding you can use that instead. But for the Java binding it seems you'll have deploy it using Maven.